# How do you replace blanks with character string in a filtered dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

In R, I'm trying to replace blank values in one column based off a character string pattern in another column.

Below is what the dataframe (df) looks:

```
 df
 qual   bdl
 U      <
 UJ   
 J
 U-     <
 UU     
 NA   
 U      <
```

And here is what I'd like the dataframe to look like:

```
 df
 qual   bdl
 U      <
 UJ     <
 J
 U-     <
 UU     <
 NA   
 U      <
```

For every row in `df$qual` that contains "U", I want `df$bdl` to contain "<".
Using the stringr package, I tried the following code:

```
data$bdl <- ifelse(str_detect(data$qual, "U") & data$bdl != "<", "<", data$bdl)
```

But I just ended up getting NAs in the whole column `df$bdl`

I'm not quiet sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Please use `dput` to add a reproducible example of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grepl`:

`df_1$bdl[grepl("U", df_1$qual)]="<"`

Output:

```
    qual bdl
1    U   <
2   UJ   <
3  <NA>   <
4    J    
5   U-   <
6   UU   <
7  <NA>    
8    U   <
```

Comment: Thanks, although I should have clarified. There are rows with `NA` in the `qual` column that have "<" in the `bdl` column, so using your would remove those. Here is an updated dataframe that more accurately represents what I'm working with:

`df_1 <- data.frame(
  qual = c("U", "UJ", NA, "J", "U-", "UU", NA, "U"),
  bdl = c("<", "", "<", "", "<", "", "", "<")
)`

Comment: @Keene: Means if `qual` contains `U` or `NA` then it should print `<` right?

Comment: No, if `qual` contains `U` then it needs `<` in `bdl`, but there can be other values in `qual` that also have `<` in `bdl`. For example, there are instances where both `J` and `NA` have `<` in `qual`, but `U` is the only value that needs to have `<`.

Comment: @Keene: Updated answer as per your requirement. Please let me know in case you have further suggestions!

Comment: @Keene: There is not `<` for the `J` in the `df_1`. Am I right?